# Problema con Docker en linux y aplicaciones react

Tags: linux, docker

Tengo un servidor de 4gb de ram , pero estoy viendo que se me crearon multiples instancias de npm start y me esta copnsumiendo todo, por que puede ser esto? Tengo apps en produccion yo, pero no creo que necesiten todos esos procesos que estan ahi, como puedo determinar cuales puedo matar con seguridad?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: probablemente haz configurado mal el task runner que reinicia la aplicacion.